# Highchart reversed column data labels

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart with reversed yAxis:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lvil/sX83S/1/)

```
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: 'white',
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        y: 10,
        style: {
            fontSize: '8px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
        }
```

I want to show the data labels inside the column like in the jsFiddle example, but can't set the position to be near the top border like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/)  or above the top border of each column.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: You would like to something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2367L/ ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan yes, but with reversed yAxis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set directly options for dataLabels to get them visible, see: http://jsfiddle.net/sX83S/2/

```
            dataLabels: {
                ...
                verticalAlign: "top",
                overflow: true,
                crop: false,
                inside: true,
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is based on fact, that you change start point of yAxis. I don't know is it possible to achieve "***top***" in your case, because the column's don't have same start points but stop at the same finish point "`150`". This give something close result, but you should think further:

```
dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,  
                color: "white",
                rotation: -90, //optional
                align: "left", // "right" or delete it at all 
                y:-150,        //this is crucial
                style: {
                    fontSize: '8px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            },
```

So, anyway you should play with y ("`y:-50`" is the "***top***" level, "`y:-150`" is the "***bottom***" level) and figure out that meaning is different for all columns.

**UPD**.: As I understand you want to place it right on the edges of each columns, alas I'm not sure is that possible.